# all master nodes are miners as well in Ethereum?

Tags: mining, nodes

I have doubts about master nodes and miners in Ethereum.

1- Do all the miners have to be full nodes as well?

2- Do all the full nodes have to be miners as well?

Comment: What do you mean with "master node"?

Comment: I mean a full node

Comment: The short answer is: 1. Yes, 2. No.

Comment: really? I think it's the opposite

Comment: Maybe it's a misunderstanding. I understand under full node a node that is completely syncing the blockchain and recalculating all the transactions. If you're a mining node, you will need this information. But you don't have to mine actually. Moreover, you can participate in mining without running a node at all, see pool mining for instance. So not exactly sure.. Maybe somone smarter here can clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

There are no master nodes in Ethereum, there are just nodes. All a miner does is hash block headers with different nonces, trying to generate a low enough hash. All a full node does is download new blocks and

Miners do need access to a node in order to generate the blocks/block headers that they hash, but they don't need to be nodes themselves. Nodes are not miners, but they do need miners in order to get new blocks.